# Expanding q-series having q-Pochhammer symbols in the summands as a power series

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I have Mathematica 11.0. I would like to see power series coefficients of a q-series (having q-Pochhammer symbols in the summands) together in order to look for certain arithmetic information.

Earlier, when I had Mathematica 9, I used to evaluate, say,

```
Series[Sum[q^(n^2 + n)/QPochhammer[q, q^2, n + 1], {n, 0, 10}], {q, 0, 10}]
```

to find the partial sum of this third order mock theta function $\nu(-q)$ up to $q^{10}$. And this used to work perfectly. However, now I just get an  output consisting of expressions like

> ```
> (1-QPochhammer^{(1, 0, 0)}[0, 0, 2] q^3
> ```

Could someone please tell me why this is happening in the newer version? I would also appreciate any alternate procedure for calculating the partial sums of a q-series written as a power series.

Comment: Use `FunctionExpand`: `Series[Sum[
  q^(n^2 + n)/QPochhammer[q, q^2, n + 1] // FunctionExpand, {n, 0, 
   10}], {q, 0, 10}]`

Comment: An alternative to using `FunctionExpand` is to use `Sum[q^(n^2 + n)/QPochhammer[q, q^2, n + 1], {n, 0, 10}] /. 
 q -> q + O[q]^10`

Comment: @CarlWoll - since the `Series` is to include `q^10`, the replacement should be `q -> q + O[q]^11`

Comment: Great. It worked! Thank you all so much!